# Query .o file symbols

Tags: ios, objective-c, unix, llvm-clang

I have an issue with recursive git submodules in my Xcode workspace. I think that llvm is picking up the wrong .m file.

I'd like to confirm this by showing the methods available in the object binary.

I know that I can use `ar -t myarchive.a` to show the `.o` files in a static library. Is there any way to drill down deeper and show the method symbols available on a specific .o?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use the `nm` command to show the symbols within `.o` or `.a` file.  See the `nm` [manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nm.1.html) for details.

```
$ nm build/IoEvent.o
```

(clipped)

```
---------------- T __ZN9ChessCore18ChessCoreExceptionC1EPKcz
---------------- T __ZN9ChessCore18ChessCoreExceptionD0Ev
---------------- T __ZN9ChessCore18ChessCoreExceptionD1Ev
---------------- D __ZN9ChessCore7IoEvent11m_classnameE
---------------- T __ZN9ChessCore7IoEvent3setEv
---------------- T __ZN9ChessCore7IoEvent5resetEv
---------------- T __ZN9ChessCore7IoEventC1Ei
---------------- T __ZN9ChessCore7IoEventC1Ev
---------------- T __ZN9ChessCore7IoEventC2Ei
---------------- T __ZN9ChessCore7IoEventC2Ev
---------------- T __ZN9ChessCore7IoEventD0Ev
---------------- T __ZN9ChessCore7IoEventD1Ev
---------------- T __ZN9ChessCore7IoEventD2Ev
---------------- T __ZNK9ChessCore18ChessCoreException4whatEv
```

If you're using C++ (I know you're not) then you can use `c++filt` to demangle those symbol names:

```
$ c++filt  __ZN9ChessCore7IoEvent5resetEv
ChessCore::IoEvent::reset()
```